# GitHub runner setup in GKE

Tags: github, kubernetes, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners, github-actions-runners

I am trying to create a GitHub actions self-host runner in GKE.
For the I created the Docker with Ubuntu base image and downloaded the GitHub runner code.

```sh
curl -o actions-runner-linux-x64-2.288.1.tar.gz -L https://github.com/actions/runner/releases/download/v2.288.1/actions-runner-linux-x64-2.288.1.tar.gz

./config.sh
```

Using the Kubernetes deployment.yaml file deployed the runner in the Kubernetes cluster, but in POD logs I am seeing the below error and the runner is unable to authenticate with the GitHub account.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ____ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ |
| / ___(_) |_| | | |_ _| |__ / \ ___| |_(_) ___ _ __ ___ |
| | | _| | __| |_| | | | | '_ \ / _ \ / __| __| |/ _ \| '_ \/ __| |
| | |_| | | |_| _ | |_| | |_) | / ___ \ (__| |_| | (_) | | | \__ \ |
| \____|_|\__|_| |_|\__,_|_.__/ /_/ \_\___|\__|_|\___/|_| |_|___/ |
| |
| Self-hosted runner registration |
| |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------



# Authentication

The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
An error occurred: Not configured
```

We are using Istio as a service mesh in our Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: Did you see [this doc](https://github.com/actions-runner-controller/actions-runner-controller)? In this doc you can find f.e. Installation, Setting Up Authentication and Deploying Using GitHub App Authentication

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned earlier I am using Istio, After whitelisting the below URL in Istio.
My issue got resolved and I am able to create a runner in the Kubernetes cluster.

api.github.com

raw.githubusercontent.com

oauth2.googleapis.com

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this documentation](https://github.com/actions-runner-controller/actions-runner-controller) before installation you should have had already installed cert-manager:

> By default, actions-runner-controller uses  [cert-manager](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/)  for certificate management of Admission Webhook. Make sure you have already installed cert-manager before you install. The installation instructions for cert-manager can be found below.
>
> - [Installing cert-manager on Kubernetes](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/)

After that you have two ways for actions-runner-controller to authenticate with the GitHub API:

> 1. Using a GitHub App (not supported for enterprise level runners due to lack of support from GitHub)
> 2. Using a PAT

See [here](https://github.com/actions-runner-controller/actions-runner-controller#:%7E:text=with%20workflow_job%20events-,Setup%20Steps,-If%20you%20want) setup steps for GitHub App Authentication and [here](https://github.com/actions-runner-controller/actions-runner-controller#deploying-using-pat-authentication) for PAT Authentication.